# Filter response returning only part of the content

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, filter

I have the below method that extracts the response and wraps it in a wrapper class.

With the debugger, I can see that `responseContent` has the full content as it should be, but when it is printed to the screen, only part of the request is returning.

I can see that the variable `data` has the entire value as it should have.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
    chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
    String responseContent = new String(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
    BasicResponse<Object> fullResponse = new BasicResponse<>();
    fullResponse.setData(new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseContent, Object.class));
    String data = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(fullResponse);
    response.getWriter().write(data);//data has the entire value
    response.getWriter().close();
}
```

Comment: Could it be that in the response `Content-Length` header is set and is lower than `data` length?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Thank you! since I'm modifying the object, the old size was left. If you want to get rewarded, post it as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the response [`Content-Length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header is set with value lower than the new data length. Make sure to set this header with new value which matches the new data length.